Amazon Cloudfront Signed URL Issue
I've been working on this for about a week. I created a cloudfront distribution for my s3 bucket, ensured it had the proper origin access control (OAC) and that the correct bucket policy gave the OAC access, ensured the distribution restrict viewer access was set to my key group, ensured the key group contained the proper public key, ensured the correct private key path was used in my code, and ensured the correct key pair ID was used. Any idea why this code is producing a signed URL with an invalid/unknown key and a 403 error? Also, I don't know if this helps, but I added a CORS policy (maybe I didn't need it?), and then I made sure my distribution behavior included not only CORS headers but also query strings. I included cookies as well (probably unnecessary, but I'm desparate to get this to work!)
using Amazon.CloudFront;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class CloudFrontSignedUrlGenerator
{
    public static string GenerateSignedUrl(string distributionDomain, string filePath, string privateKeyFilePath, string keyPairId, DateTime expirationDate)
    {
        string resourceUrl = $"https://{distributionDomain}/{filePath}";

        // Create the policy document
        var policy = new
        {
            Statement = new[]
            {
                new
                {
                    Resource = resourceUrl,
                    Condition = new
                    {
                        DateLessThan = new { EpochTime = ((DateTimeOffset)expirationDate).ToUnixTimeSeconds() }
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        string policyJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(policy);

        // Load the private key
        string privateKey = File.ReadAllText(privateKeyFilePath);

        // Sign the policy
        string signature = SignPolicyWithRSA(policyJson, privateKey);

        // Construct signed URL
        return $"{resourceUrl}?Policy={Uri.EscapeDataString(policyJson)}&Signature={signature}&Key-Pair-Id={keyPairId}";
    }

    private static string SignPolicyWithRSA(string policyJson, string privateKey)
    {
        using (RSA rsa = RSA.Create())
        {
            rsa.ImportFromPem(privateKey);
            byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(policyJson);
            byte[] signature = rsa.SignData(data, HashAlgorithmName.SHA1, RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1);

            // Make Base64 signature URL-safe
            return Convert.ToBase64String(signature)
                .Replace('+', '-')
                .Replace('/', '_')
                .Replace("=", "");
        }
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        string distributionDomain = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX.cloudfront.net";
        string filePath = "WindowsForm_1/20241205_WFASample.mp4";
        string privateKeyFilePath = "C:\\Users\\USERNAME\\OneDrive\\Coding\\AmazonWebServices\\KeyPair\\PrivateKey\\pk-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.pem";
        string keyPairId = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
        DateTime expirationDate = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(1);

        string signedUrl = GenerateSignedUrl(distributionDomain, filePath, privateKeyFilePath, keyPairId, expirationDate);

        Console.WriteLine($"Generated Signed URL: {signedUrl}");
    }
}


I'd be tempted to test using the awscli cloudfront sign just to rule out potential bugs in your code.
